# Can I populate datagrid using ArrayCollection.List or ArrayCollection.Source?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have an `ArrayCollection` from a result handler in Flex that has FilterFunction, List, Source, Length.

How can I populate the datagrid using this data?
.....

Answer (score 1):

Set the `DataProvider` value on the DataGrid to the ArrayCollection. It will use this to populate the display.

See the demo on the bottom of [this page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_6.html).